# Is SLS capable of launching the core stage into LEO?

Tags: nasa, low-earth-orbit, launch-vehicle, sls, ssto

After watching the Hazegrayart video [If Rockets were Transparent](https://youtu.be/su9EVeHqizY) I realized that I didn't really have a clear idea what the [Space Launch System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Launch_System) (SLS) is capable of doing.

**Question:** Is SLS capable of launching the core stage into LEO? If so, how much additional payload mass could it put there?

I'll note that this question was raised previously by @leftaroundabout in a comment below [Could the SLS reach orbit without solid rocket boosters?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33330/12102)

"bonus points:" If so, would that be considered as [SSTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-stage-to-orbit)?

Comment: What, you mean keeping the boosters and carrying them all the way to orbit...?

Comment: Well, then it's not much different from calling the Shuttle an SSTO.

Comment: This is kind of equivalent of "is SLS capable of launching the core stage into LEO". A typical satellite is around 3000kg which is kind of negligible compared with the empty weight of the core stage itself.

Comment: Also, if you allow SRB then it's more like a 1.5-STO like the recent 4th CZ-5 launch, while if you strictly require SSTO without SRB then is the thing capable of lift off by itself?

Comment: @user3528438 I've changed the question accordingly, thanks! Also [Could the SLS reach orbit without solid rocket boosters?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33330/12102) has been answered with "Fully fueled, the first stage alone has only an 0.77:1 thrust-to-weight ratio"

Comment: https://www.nasa.gov/exploration/systems/sls/to-the-moon.html  Here NASA says SLS is capable of delivering a 95 metric ton total upper stage and payload to LEO (a 100 mile sub-LEO?) https://silverbirdastronautics.com/LVperform.html This site actually allows you to calculate the payload capacity.

Comment: @user3528438 I think that’s a good basis for writing an answer.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I'm just collecting some clues but not expert in this area. The NASA source provide no specific orbit parameter while the other one didn't provide any reference at all. My knowledge on orbital dynamics is near 0 so I'll leave it to true experts.

Comment: @user3528438 If you can find dry and total masses and an Isp is at least an estimate-based educated guess possible?

Comment: @uhoh You're asking about SLS, with boosters, and no upper stage, right? Silverbird can do that configuration.

Comment: There's some very nice work in that transparent rocket animation, by the way.

Comment: @RussellBorogove ya there's a lot going on in the video, I like it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Silverbird](https://silverbirdastronautics.com/LVperform.html), SLS Block 1 with boosters but no upper stage, launching from Canaveral into a 185km circular orbit at 28º inclination, can orbit an estimated 66 tons of payload. (It actually gives a wide range of payload masses, 50-85 tons, because of uncertainties in its model of the SLS. I don't know how current Silverbird's data is.)

To the ISS 400km x 51º orbit its best estimate is 58 tons with an range of 42-76 tons.

NASA's 95 tons to 160km @ 28º claim, I assume, includes a final orbital insertion burn done with the ICPS upper stage.

This is not SSTO; the boosters function as a stage.

Comment: Wow it can! So very roughly, double of the Space Shuttle?

Comment: Either 0.6x or 2.5x shuttle payload depending on whether you count the orbiter as  payload.